# What is the difference between the Pseudo F Index and the F Statistic?

Tags: anova, clustering, f-statistic

I'm wondering what the difference between the Pseudo F Index and the F Statistic is.

The Pseudo F Index is used in clustering analysis as an index to determine the the right number of clusters in a dataset. Its defined as follows:

[image]

[Link to the source](http://cda.psych.uiuc.edu/multivariate_fall_2012/systat_cluster_manual.pdf)

The F Statistic is from the common ANOVA:

[image: F-Statistic]

[Link to the source](http://faculty.uncfsu.edu/dwallace/lesson%2015.pdf)

What is the difference in the two calculations? If there is none, why is the index for clustering called "Pseudo F Index" and not simply "F Index" or "F statistic"? It is because in the case of clustering, you cannot perform hypothesis testing based on this statistic?